# ASPNET Core REST API - allow requests by specific domain groups or local users

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, authorization

We are using ASPNET Core 6, building a REST API.
Calling API methods must be allowed only for a local user or members of a specific domain group. I have read a lot about this, but I am confused.

In the APS.NET world we simple add some limitations to the web.config and IIS handled the problem:

- IIS Windows + Basic AUTH set ON, Anonymus OFF
- web.config is modified:

  ```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="AD\Managers" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="LOCAL_TEST_USER" />
      </authorization>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  ```

As far as I see this web.config section is totally ignored by the IIS now :( Or at least I was able to execute some rest api call as an 'outsider' user.

I wonder what is the simplest and easiest way to reproduce the same behavior using ASPNET Core 6.

Comment: The "solution" means that I must decorate all my controllers with an Authorize attribute. It means (for me) that the authorization rule is no more pre-handled by the IIS but the code itself. Isn't there any solution to put all the hard work to IIS?

Comment: The question is closed - nor I have an answer. The IIS can handle it using the old way mentioned above. My problem was that the "IIS URL Authorization module" was not installed, and so the IIS "skipped" this section.